# Export to a Relative Path

Tags: files-and-directories

Suppose I have a folder `'work'` with two subfolders `'mathematica'` and `'figures'`. The thing I would like to do is run a Mathematica notebook stored in the `'mathematica'` folder (the path is `"C:\\Users\\Sam\\documents\\work\\mathematica\\mynotebook.nb"`) and export a figure it produces into the `'figures'` folder with the name `'Fig13a.pdf'`. Normally, it can be done by supplying the full path 
`Export["C:\\Users\\Sam\\documents\\work\\figures\\Fig13a.pdf", pic1];`

My question is, in case at some future point I may want to rename the `'work'` folder or move the folder as a whole to a different place, is there a way I can use some sort of "relative path" such that I can only supply explicitly this part of the path `"...\\figures\\Fig13a.pdf"` to the `Export` command?

Comment: Yes, you can use the absolute or relative syntax. The current directory is given by `Directory[]`.

Comment: Relative paths are interpreted relative to `Directory[]`, not the notebook's location. Look up `NotebookDirectory` and `FileNameJoin` to be able to build the path you need. Alternatively, use `SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]` and then just use relative paths afterwards.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you very much. If I use the `FileNameJoin` method, how do I get rid of the `\\mathematica` part in the returned value `C:\\Users\\Sam\\documents\\work\\mathematica`  from the  `NotebookDirectory` command?

Comment: You don't need to. You can use `"C:\\Users\\Sam\\documents\\work\\mathematica\\..\\figures"`